# Как подключиться к БД удаленно?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

У клиента есть сайт который размещен на платном хостинге. Как мне подключиться к БД сайта удаленно через OS Panel? Есть все доступы к БД и к личному кабинету хостинга. Доступы в БД открыты для всех.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите настройки ftp (и подключения к базам: адрес для внешних подключений, порт, сокет, имя пользователя и прочее - возможно,  там нужны дополнительные разрешения) в технической информации в панели хостинга.

Кроме того - возможно, оптимальнее скачать дамп базы и просто установить в OS Panel и работать более спокойно.